# Is circular reasoning always wrong?

Tags: logic, reason, circularity

I was wondering if circular reasoning is always a problem I was thinking about something like this if A then B, And If B then A.

Premise. A is true

Conclusion. B is true.

All this shows is that B logically follows from A being true, Why is this form of circular reasoning logically wrong? it seems like an inductive argument to me.

Comment: This is not circular reasoning, this is proving that A and B are [logically equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence). It may well be informative when the equivalence is non-obvious. Circular reasoning would, literally, be "if A and B then A", or, informally, when A is replaced in the premise by some A' *transparently* equivalent to it. Even then it is not *logically* wrong, just *substantively* uninformative, and hence an informal fallacy.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks I understand I'm going to leave this up for a few more people to answer although yeah that makes that sounds correct to me.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a circular argument, it's an [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) statement.

There's nothing formally wrong with circular arguments. A therefore A is always true. They just don't prove anything, since they're logically identical to the premise by itself. If I am purple, then I am purple. I am not, in fact, purple. *If I am purple, then I am purple, therefore you should believe that I am purple* is a garden variety non-sequitur.

Answer (score 3):

Quite the opposite. Circular reasoning is always correct, it is just useless.

“If A then A” is absolutely true. It just doesn’t tell you anything about A. Now what will happen that someone tries to prove A. They start a reasonable proof, then sneak in the completely unproven statement A, then end up with A. It may not be directly, because that would be too obvious. Sometimes it is very well hidden that a proof is circular.